# Checking Duplicate Parenthesis Using stacks in java

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, parentheses

The code is to check weather Duplicate parenthesis exist or not ..
I am getting **true** for every string. I am unable to find where I am wrong

```
public class DuplicatePar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "((a+b)+c)";
        System.out.println(dupliPar(str));
    }
    public static boolean dupliPar(String str){
        Stack<Character> s = new Stack<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) != ')'){
                s.push(str.charAt(i));
            }
            if(str.charAt(i) == ')' && s.peek() != '('){
                while(s.peek() !='('){                                      
                    s.pop();
                }
                s.pop();
            }
          
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just follow through the logic for i = 0.  The first character is not a closing parenthesis therefore you return 'true'.   I haven't bothered to think it through, but maybe the second 'if' should be 'else if'.

Comment: The second `if` must be `else if` 

Yeah it worked but can you explain what makes it difference though initially there are two `if ` with two  different conditions  so that only one `if` work at a time , right?

Comment: There is no connection between the title and the body !

Comment: no idea what yo are asking.  what are the inputs and expected output?

Comment: @SBM see my answer for explanation.

Comment: @Yves Daoust - sorry for it

Comment: Though this may be obvious to you, I don't know what you call "duplicate parenthesis". This can be understood in different ways.

Comment: @Yves Daoust--ig Its  a name of the standard Question --Of checking unnecessary brackets in Expression or just search "duplicate parenthesis"  on search engine for more clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written -

```
        if(str.charAt(i) != ')'){
            s.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        if(str.charAt(i) == ')' && s.peek() != '('){
            while(s.peek() !='('){                                      
                s.pop();
            }
            s.pop();
        }
      
        else{
            return true;
        }
```

Suppose the first char is '(',  The condition of the first 'if' is true (it's not a close parenthesis) so we execute the controlled statement (push to stack).

We're now done with that 'if'.  The second 'if' has a false condition so we execute the associated 'else' clause and immediately return a 'true' result.

With 'else' added:

```
        if(str.charAt(i) != ')'){
            s.push(str.charAt(i));
        }
        else if(str.charAt(i) == ')' && s.peek() != '('){
            while(s.peek() !='('){                                      
                s.pop();
            }
            s.pop();
        }
      
        else{
            return true;
        }
```

Again, suppose the first char is '(',  The condition of the first 'if' is true (it's not a close parenthesis) so we execute the controlled statement (push to stack).

And therefore we do not execute the 'else' clause of the first 'if' statment.  The 'else' clause is the entire second if-else construction.  Thus we don't return the incorrect result, but keep processing the input string.

---

That's the solution to the specific problem you reported, but I am not convinced the code works in all cases.  Consider the input string ")(" for example.

Comment: Yes I got what makes it difference from your comment only , that using double `if `  versus`if` and `else if` ,
 yeah Its correct what example you mentioned, but In question it is given  * Balanced expression* so that no wrong patterned  parentheses present, only thing is to find the duplicates